# Access a single character from txt file in c#

Tags: c#, string, text

How can I access a single character from a txt file?

The code should look like this:

```
char foo = * character x,y *
```

or

```
char foo = * character number x *
```

By x and y I indeed mean x = character number in that line. y = line number.

The txt file is just a bunch of 0's and 1's and I want to find out if the character is a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Your question does not seem to make much sense to me...

Comment: When you say "character" do you mean in a particular encoding, or can we assume you are talking about a byte?

Comment: @Theraot the txt file is just a bunch of 0's and 1's and I want to find out if the character is a 0 or a 1. -Edit: by x and y I indeed mean x = character number in that line. y = line number.

Comment: You can access strings as character arrays.

Comment: Easiest: use File.ReadAllLines() and access the resulting `string[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
char GetChar(string sFilePath, int iLineNumber, int iOffset)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFilePath))
    {
        string sLine = string.Empty;
        while (iLineNumber-- > 0)
            sLine = sr.ReadLine();

        return sLine[iOffset - 1];
    }
}
```

Usage: get the 4th character from 2nd line in examplefile.txt

```
char c = GetChar("examplefile.txt", 2, 4);
```

Edit (following Theraot's comment) - support file encoding in StreamReader initialization.

```
char GetChar(string sFilePath, int iLineNumber, int iOffset, Encoding oEncoding)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sFilePath, oEncoding))
    {
        string sLine = string.Empty;
        while (iLineNumber-- > 0)
            sLine = sr.ReadLine();

        return sLine[iOffset - 1];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
char c = GetChar(sFilePath, 2, 4, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to add your own validations, as it will throw exception if there is no 4th character in line number 2.

Comment: +1: Since the OP has said he wants line number and character in the line, this is the way to go (edit: unless OP needs some fancy line separator, which I doubt). I have removed my answer in favor of yours. I would like to add that `StreamReader` has constructor overloads that accept `System.Text.Encoding`.

Comment: Thank you Theraot, I'll change it to StreamReader c-tor which also gets the encoding. Raymond - you welcome.

Comment: Orel, when I run my code I get the following error on ''return sLine[iOffset - 1];: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' What could be causing this problem? I don't really understand your code so I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance. I am sorry if I am vague.

Comment: Orel, I already figured it out sorry haha. I am used to saying x,y however in your code it's y,x even though you explained it well. Thanks again